# Remainder when $6^{44}. (22)!+3$ is divided by $23$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I have information about Euler theorem: $a^{p}=a\mod{p}$ and Wilson's theorem: $(p-1)!+1=0\mod{p}$. But I have no clue how to approach this one. Please give some hints.

Comment: Well, those are the tools. What is $22!\pmod {23}$ for example,?

Comment: Knowing $23=22+1$ and $44= 2 \times 22$ may help

Comment: $\!\bmod 23\!:\ \color{#c00}{22!\equiv -1}\,$ by Wilson, and Fermat $\Rightarrow 6^{22}\equiv 1\Rightarrow \color{#0a0}{6^{44} = (6^{22})^2\equiv 1^2\equiv 1},\,$ so $\,\color{#0a0}{6^{44}}\,\color{#c00}{22!}+3\equiv \color{#0a0}1\,(\color{#c00}{-1})+3\equiv 2\,$ by [Congruence Sum & Product Rules](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242)